# Embedding MySQL into JavaFx

Tags: mysql, javafx

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to embed a data item from MySQL into a JavaFX application. There are also four buttons to iterate through each column, one for the first, previous, next, and last.  This what I've got so far, but I'm not sure how to approach this.  Any feedback would be helpful.

```
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class ImpoundGUI1 extends Application{
        private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.driver";
        private static final String DB_URL = "jdbimpoundc:mysql://localhost.impound?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

    public void start(Stage stage){
        Button first = new Button("First");
        Button prev = new Button("Previous");
        Button next = new Button("Next");
        Button last = new Button("Last");

        TextField vin = new TextField();
        TextField plateNumber = new TextField();
        TextField make = new TextField();
        TextField model = new TextField();
        TextField year = new TextField();
        TextField color = new TextField();

        Label v = new Label("VIN");
        Label p = new Label("License Plate");
        Label m1 = new Label("Make");
        Label m2 = new Label("Model");
        Label y = new Label ("Year");
        Label c = new Label ("Color");

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();

        pane.add(v, 0, 0);
        pane.add(p, 0, 1);
        pane.add(m1, 0, 2);
        pane.add(m2, 0, 3);
        pane.add(y, 0, 4);
        pane.add(c, 0, 5);
        pane.add(vin, 9, 0);
        pane.add(plateNumber, 9, 1);
        pane.add(make, 9, 2);
        pane.add(model, 9, 3);
        pane.add(year, 9, 4);
        pane.add(color, 9, 5);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setHgrow(first, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox.setHgrow(prev, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox.setHgrow(next, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox.setHgrow(last, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(first,prev,next,last);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(pane,hbox);

        Connection connect = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        final String userName = "root";
        final String password = "bakq";

        first.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){;


        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            try{
                Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,userName,password);

            }
        });


        stage.setTitle("Impound Lot");
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 205);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*I would imagine calling the .getText() method would work.
Thanks.

Comment: What's going on with your `first.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){;`? Is this code compiling?

Comment: You can try to get some ideas from [here](https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample).

Comment: I would create some kind of `Vehicle` object. If you database it not to big, try reading in all rows using `Select * from vehicle`. Store those rows into a `List<Vehicle>`. Use the List throughout your code.

Comment: There are multiple syntactic errors: You cannot assign a local variable from inside a anonymus class. A `try` without resources, `catch` or `finally` won't work either.

Comment: A lot of this isn't even done, but thanks for the information.